# libavcodec get video duration and framerate

Tags: video, ffmpeg, duration, frame-rate, libavcodec

I have a video encoded in `.3gp` `h.264` and I am looking to get its framerate and duration in C. Here is the code I use after opening the file and finding the appropriate codecs:

```
AVRational rational = gVideoCodecCtx->time_base;

LOGI(10, "numerator is %i", rational.num);
LOGI(10, "denominator is %i", rational.den);
LOGI(10, "duration is %d", gFormatCtx->duration);
LOGI(10, "fps is %d", (double)av_q2d(rational));
```

And here is the output:

```
12-02 12:30:19.819: I/FFmpegTest(23903): numerator is 1
12-02 12:30:19.819: I/FFmpegTest(23903): denominator is 180000
12-02 12:30:19.819: I/FFmpegTest(23903): duration is 6594490
12-02 12:30:19.819: I/FFmpegTest(23903): fps is 1692926992
```

From the documentation I understand that the duration is meant to be "duration/time_base" which gives me `6594490 / 180000 = 36.6`. The duration of my video file is `6 seconds` and I do not know where this factor of `6` would come from.

Also the framerate seems to be completely off.

It is currenlty hard to find help as a lot of tutorials use deprecated methods and the documentation does not give examples.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit:**
Thanks to the comment below I managed to print the following

```
12-02 18:59:36.279: I/FFmpegTest(435): numerator is 1
12-02 18:59:36.279: I/FFmpegTest(435): denominator is 180000
12-02 18:59:36.279: I/FFmpegTest(435): duration is 6594490
12-02 18:59:36.279: I/FFmpegTest(435): fps is 0.000006
```

I also managed to find out a frame's timestamp in `msec` with this:

```
int msec = 1000*(packet.pts * timeBase * gVideoCodecCtx->ticks_per_frame);
```

This returns me something that's roughly `33fps` (I expect `30`). But I can't figure out how to retrieve the duration. The documentation says "duration of the stream, in `AV_TIME_BASE` fractional seconds" but `6594490 * 0.000006 = 39.5` - the correct duration is `6.3` seconds). Also the exact fps is `30` but nor sure how to get from `0.000006` to `30` with the above figures)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

FPS can be obtained this way:

```c
const double FPS = (double)videoStream->r_frame_rate.num / (double)videoStream->r_frame_rate.den;
```

where `videoStream` is:

```c
AVFormatContext * format = NULL;
if ( avformat_open_input( & format, "my_video.mkv", NULL, NULL ) != 0 ) ) on_error();
if ( avformat_find_stream_info( format, NULL ) < 0) on_error();
//av_dump_format( format, 0, "my_video.mkv", false );
AVCodec * video_dec = (AVCodec*)1;
const auto video_stream_index = av_find_best_stream( format, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, & video_dec, 0 );
if ( video_stream_index < 0 ) on_error();
const auto videoStream = format->streams[ video_stream_index ];
```

Answer (score -2):

Your fps print is garbage because it is supposed to be %lf not %d.
Why don't you check the other parameters types also once.

Comment: @Tishu, what do you get if you either do a ffprobe on the file or ffmpeg -i file without anything else. On console you will get what ffmpeg thinks is the framerate duration etc.